# validation on if condition in Laravel

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-5

How to give a validation on if condition like in my project case there are two inputs one is deal type and one is event name .so i have to give a condition like if deal type is single then i have to validate that event name otherwise no.

Here is my view :

```
<select name="deal_type">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="annual">Annual</option>
       <option value="single">Single</option>
</select>

 <select name="eventname">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="event1">Event1</option>
      <option value="event2">event2</option>
</select>
```

my validation request.php :

```
public function rules()
    {
         return [
                'deal_type'=>'required',
                'eventname'=>'required_if:deal_type,single'
             ]; 
}
```

I was trying something like above but it is not working .Any suggestions please.

Comment: is there any error, or it just evaluates to false ?

Comment: just i have to evaluate that event field as required field based on deal type value as single.

Comment: It is not showing event name as required  field ..rest all validation is working

Comment: can you try this ? not sure if this is of any use but worth a try https://gist.github.com/juice49/4176954

Comment: @jaysingkar : it says error like `Method [validateRequiredIfAttribute] does not exist.`  that means i have to add required_if attribute in validator.php ??

Comment: yes.. you would need to use that. or you can use a little hack to add a required to your other element. Will post it in answer as it is little long to post here

Comment: required_if is already included with Laravel validation. Can you post you're validation code? where you validate the fields?

Comment: @CanCelik : i have posted my validation code already i.e request.php

Comment: @HarshithaNaidu what is the error message you are getting? why is it not working?